# Exception for redirect iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, ubuntu-18.04

How to make an exception to not redirect to localhost:port?

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two variants:

Variant 1: Exclude localhost destination in the rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

This is quick-and-easy, effective, but limited solution.

Variant 2: Make a rule before this one, which doesn't redirect. It will match and finish processing this chain, so the following rules will not get executed, including your reidrect:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

This variant is more general, applicable to the case you have a list of exceptions that you can't express together in a single rule.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify, what you want to do? If I am not mistaken your rule has only effect on localhost!?

To have "exceptions" just can add the same line before it and change `-j ACCEPT` and of course the condition for the exception.